# PrimeReact DataTable Height issue

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I am using DataTable in primeReact, to render some data, I would like to make it display to full size of the window. table size only matches the data size. here's my code.

```
                <div style={{ padding: '0rem 1rem 1rem 1rem' }}>
                    <DataTable value={attributes} 
                        showGridlines
                        stripedRows
                        resizableColumns 
                        columnResizeMode="fit"
                        paginator
                        rows={12}>
                        <Column field="name" header="Name"></Column>
                        <Column field="displayName" header="Display Name"></Column>
                        <Column field="headerName" header="Header Name"></Column>
                        <Column field="editable" header="Editable" body={editableBodyTemplate}></Column>
                        <Column field="isDefault" header="Is Default" body={isDefaultBodyTemplate}></Column>
                    </DataTable>
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should add a `style={{minHeight: '95vh'}}` property to the DataTable element :)